# Grab HTML code stored in Powershell array to retrieve certain string

Tags: html, arrays, regex, powershell

```
<div class="primary-title-and-description">
    <h1>
        Title Here
    </h1>

    <p>
        Paragraph Here
    </p>
</div>
```

Hi

I am trying to get the values within the `<h1></h1>` only from the `<div class="primary-title-and-description">`. How do I go about doing that?

Above is just a snippet of code which I use the webClient.DownloadString($URL) to get the above.
What powershell command can get me only the output as below?
Title Here

Answer (score 2):

use function like 
$> Get-Title < put here webpage link >

This will get source-code of webpage and using regex cut everything outside < h1> and < /h1>

```css
Function Get-Title { 
    param([string] $url)
  
    $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
    $data = $webClient.downloadstring($url) 
    $title = [regex] '(?<=<h1>)([\S\s]*?)(?=</h1>)' 
    write-Host $title.Match($data).value.trim() 
}
```

Good Luck

---

REMEMBER TO MARK ANSWER AS USEFUL IF HELPED